# java jbox2D PolygonShape set position

Tags: java, position, shapes, jbox2d

I develop jbox2d (java) and I have a problem when I create a polygon shape.

I can not choose the position of my polygon, there is a field "m_centroid" I defined as the center of my window. The polygon remains in the left corner.

```
public class Player {
    private Body body;

    public Player(World world) {
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.angle = (float) Math.toRadians(0.0f);
        bodyDef.position.set(800.0f / 2, 600.0f / 2);
        bodyDef.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;

        /*Vec2[] vertices = {
            new Vec2(bodyDef.position.x, bodyDef.position.y - 10.0f),
            new Vec2(bodyDef.position.x + 10.0f, bodyDef.position.y + 10.0f),
            new Vec2(bodyDef.position.x - 10.0f, bodyDef.position.y + 10.0f)
        };*/

        Vec2[] vertices = {
                new Vec2(0.0f, - 10.0f),
                new Vec2(+ 10.0f, + 10.0f),
                new Vec2(- 10.0f, + 10.0f)
        };

        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.set(vertices, vertices.length);
        shape.m_centroid.set(bodyDef.position);

        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = shape;
        fixtureDef.density = 0.5f;
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
        fixtureDef.restitution = 0.5f;

        body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Answer (score 0):

The centroid is supposed to be the center of the polygon in local coordinates, and is used for torque/mass calculations.  You shouldn't be modifying that.  Instead, you need to use the transform on the Body.  Try something like `body.getTransform().setPos(___)`.